# Changing kernel page permission for allowing user access

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, kernel, mmu

In x86 or x64 Linux, I am trying to make a kernel module that changes specific kernel page permission to allow user application accessing that memory. For example, if there is a readable kernel page at 0xC0001000(say it's 3:1 split), I want to change user/supervisor bit of this page and allow user applications to do something like this.

```
int* m = 0xC0001000;
printf("reading kernel memory from user : %08x\n", *m);
```

In my kernel module, I changed the access bit of corresponding kernel memory page from 0x67 to 0x63 (lower bits 111 -> 011) clearing the supervisor bit.

After that, I flushed the TLB of virtual address 0xc0001000 using invdpg instruction.
I have confirmed that the page entry I manipulated was indeed the corresponding one.
However, accessing 0xC0001000 from user application still causes me segmentation fault.
Am I missing something important here? perhaps cs segment and GDT? or is that irrelevant?

Some advice would be nice, thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

From your kernel module you can just change the effective user id to 0 to let it read [`/dev/kmem`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html),

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I want... what I want is making user application(CPL3) directly accessing kernel virtual address. this is the goal it self

Comment: @daehee Well, `/dev/kmem` is the kernel virtual address space, and for a user-space application to access it all it needs is root privelege.